# get duration of song before the player loads

Tags: jquery, jplayer

Can I get it with something similar to :

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("getDuration") ?
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jPlayer puts information about the file being played into the `data` collection for the element it's bound to. Try this:

```
var duration = $("#jquery_jplayer_1").data("jPlayer").status.duration;
```